# Create file with variable name in Python

Tags: python, xml, azure-blob-storage

I am creating a series xml files in python loop and send to Azure blob container.  The filenames contain variables that correspond to the date/time.  I've successfully created the files using no directory or folder but instead just sending them to the main container.  I would like to add a directory or folder to place created files so they go here:

```
save_path = '/this/is/a/directory/thatsends/filestoAzureContainer'
name_of_file = '%s_%s_%s.xml' %(model, date_run_stamp, forecast_hour)
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, "/newDirectoryorFolder", name_of_file)
```

I have tried several different combinations, including the one above, (using "/" at end of save_path, created new variable for string of the "newDirectoryFolder" for the directory and none are creating the files.

This works to send to main container but looking to add files to their own folder.

```
for x in range(0, 75, 3):
  forecast = x * 3600
  model = model1
  try:
   forecast_hour = str(forecast/3600) + "h"
   date_run_stamp = date_formatted.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H") 
  
   def createXMLfile():
    root = xml.Element("Data")
    tree = xml.ElementTree(root)
  
    save_path = '/this/is/a/directory/thatsends/filestoAzureContainer'
    name_of_file = '%s_%s_%s.xml' %(model, date_run_stamp, forecast_hour)
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file)
    with open(completeName, "wb") as f:
      tree.write(f)

   if __name__=="__main__":
    creatXMLfile()

  except Exception:
    print("Warning: unable to create file for forecast hour '{forecast}'")
```

Comment: Without having a test case to work with, this appears like it should work just fine. **Though** the use of a slash in the "/newDirectoryorFolder" part of  `completeName = os.path.join(save_path, "/newDirectoryorFolder", name_of_file)` will mean the `save_path` part is ignored and your things will be saved at `<root>/newDirectoryorFolder` so if that's present in your test code, remove the slash.

Comment: What do you mean by `This works to send to main container but looking to add files to their own folder.`? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If I leave out any mention of a directory, i.e. "newDirectoryorFolder", the code works as desinged and sends the files directly to the main blob container.  But I would like to separate these files from others in the container by way of a directory or folder.